# Is it possible to patch a dotnet function on the fly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, reverse-engineering

Recently I found an architect-often-used .net program has implemented a function wrongly. So I successfully **patched it** using ILSpy and Reflexil **in a static way of modifying binaries**. However, it is annoying that you need to patch it and remove StrongNameCheck again when new minor version releases. (btw, the author believes it is a feature instead of a bug)

Hopefully, the program fully supports assemblies as a plugin. And my target is **a public non-static member function in a public class** which can be directly called by plugins. Is there a way to patch the function **on the fly**?

I usually use some APIHook tricks in unmanaged C++ but dotnet is really a different thing. In this case, I want the modification still valid after my assembly unloads (so more similar to a patch, not a hook).

Comment: I've never used this but... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/463508/NET-CLR-Injection-Modify-IL-Code-during-Run-time

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.outercurve.org/blog/2014/03/25/Strongnaming-I-Do-Not-Think-It-Means-What-You-Thin) article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't monkey patch code.  Add the functionality to your code base and call that function.  Or write an adapter class that wraps the underlying assembly, which is much neater.

If the author of the code thinks it's not a bug then it may be in there for reasons you don't understand and could be part of any number of bug fixes.

Comment: plus 1 for adapter class that wraps. In general this whole post is right on the money!

Comment: Thank you. It is actually a performance degradation under a very specific circumstance. The patch involves a replacement in certain algorithm. But I agree it is true that patching code may lead to unknown bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can do it with code injection. But you need to know some MSIL. There is also a library for that which is called `Mono.Cecil`.

Here is a example code

```
        Console.WriteLine("> INJECTING INTO 12345.EXE..." + Environment.NewLine);
        AssemblyDefinition asm = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(@"C:\dummy.exe");
        var writeLineMethod = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        var writeLineRef = asm.MainModule.Import(writeLineMethod);
        var pStartMethod = typeof(Process).GetMethod("Start", new Type[] { typeof(string) });
        var pStartRef = asm.MainModule.Import(pStartMethod);

        foreach (var typeDef in asm.MainModule.Types)
        {
            foreach (var method in typeDef.Methods) 
            {
                //Let's push a string using the Ldstr Opcode to the stack
                method.Body.Instructions.Insert(0, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, "INJECTED!"));

                //We add the call to the Console.WriteLine() method. It will read from the stack
                method.Body.Instructions.Insert(1, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, writeLineRef));

                //We push the path of the executable you want to run to the stack
                method.Body.Instructions.Insert(2, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Ldstr, @"calc.exe"));

                //Adding the call to the Process.Start() method, It will read from the stack
                method.Body.Instructions.Insert(3, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Call, pStartRef));

                //Removing the value from stack with pop
                method.Body.Instructions.Insert(4, Instruction.Create(OpCodes.Pop));
            }
        }
        asm.Write("12345.exe"); //Now we just save the new assembly
```

Comment: Thank you. You've proposed a way of automated modifying binaries and I think it is OK (since I really don't know much about Mono.Cecil).